# Show taxonomy name in drupal content listing page

Tags: drupal

In drupal website's content listing page in Administrator 
( Home » Administer » Content management), 
currently we have only (Title|Type|Author|Status|Operations) displayed.  I wanted to show the taxonomy name also in the same listing.  How can we accomplish this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the simplest solution, I know - it's to create custom view with exposed filters, and to make it alternative content management system.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try installing Views Bulk Operations (http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations). It includes a view named admin_content to which you can add fields (you will need to enable the view first). The field I am using to show taxonomy terms for each listed node is "Taxonomy: All terms." To make it easier to access
 the view, I created a menu link for the page and placed the menu link in the admin menu under Administer > Content.